# Error with installation of programs

Tags: updates, package-management

I'm using 10.04 and getting an error trying to install new software:

```
The previous installation hasn't been completed.
The installation could have failed because of an error in the corresponding software package or it was canceled in an unfriendly way. You have to repair this before you can install or remove any further software.
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and enter

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This should finish up the previous installation and solve the problem.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept my answer so others can see that this solved your problem.